# PosPrinter - Change default font

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am using Microsoft POS for .NET library for printing a receipt on an EPSON thermal printer (TM-T70II). The printing command is done by using this library and created Service Object.

I am trying to change the default font which the device prints. If I have understood well, the device has two hardware embedded fonts FontA and FontB. If i switch the default selected, I do not see any difference.
The printer supports APD5 utility for font substitution, but it's not clear if this is supported on the OPOS driver.

Comment: Where did you read that it has two fronts? The specifications I found say that it only has one font. https://www.epson.eu/products/sd/pos-printer/epson-tm-t70ii-series#specifications